# URL for adding product to Shopping Cart

Tags: shopping-cart

Hey I´m trying to send a URL to customers where they already have products in the shopping cart.

I used this method

```
mywebsite/checkout/cart/add/product/PRODUCTID/qty/NUMBER/form_key/WSFiE69HmvU854G2
```

And it also adds a product but somehow it doesn´t show up, see image below.

[image: No product is in the cart]

Any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried so far to debug? Are there any errors? Does it work via the normal add to cart way?

Comment: On other pages the product add to cart works fine.

Comment: I wonder if the form_key is expiring

Comment: Yes, ditch form_key, it's session dependent. And use uenc parameter if you need it. It contains a go back url encoded.

Comment: I´ve tried to remove the form_key but have the same result. What is the uenc parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
http://www.example.com/checkout/cart/add/product/PRODUCTID/
```

That worked for me. Sadly I can´t use the product SKU which I hoped for.